# How to export a ssl server certificate using php

Tags: php, openssl, ssl-certificate

I want to access the whole ssl server certificate (both child and parent (CA)).

I can get the child certificate details by [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464113/is-it-possible-to-read-ssl-information-in-php-from-any-website).

Will someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

The same technique applies but instead of the `['peer_certificate']` element there should also be a chain element. I don't know what it's called but a bit of research or experiment will tell you. The chain element will itself be an array and you will need to parse each element of it.

Comment: i use `$output = shell_exec('openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host.host:443');` to get my work done, where $output is string in well format,