# Extract certificate from HTTPS site

Tags: php, https, certificate, ssl-certificate, pem

I need to extract the public key (preferably in PEM format) that a site uses to identify itself with.

E.g. a function that takes a URL as an argument (`https://www.example.com/`), then establish a connection to that site and fetches the certificate.

Any ideas about how it could be solved with PHP code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get SSL certificate info with CURL in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081042/how-to-get-ssl-certificate-info-with-curl-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `openssl` to extract the certificate.

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 > file.txt
```

You will find the certificate in `file.txt` between `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`, and you can extract it from there. I don't see a way to use the [PHP OpenSSL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) module to do this from within PHP though, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This [online tool](https://8gwifi.org/certs.jsp) to perform extraction of all certificate chain

[image]