# How to get SSL certificate information using PHP

Tags: php, ssl, curl, openssl

I want to gather all the necessary information of a SSL Certificate using PHP :

->Validity Date

->Fingerprints

->Public Key

->And all other parameters

I tried with other solutions available through SO or PHP_manual but was unable to fetch all required information.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: information of your site or another site?

Comment: You will find your answer in this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081042/how-to-get-ssl-certificate-info-with-curl-in-php

Comment: Thank you but i have already looked over SO solution (mentioned above) and doesn't solve my query.
@PrasathAlbert I have looking for info about any certificate (.crt) of any site.

Comment: Hi @djadmin I've same requirement. Did you solve your problem.? If yes can you please tell me.