# How to set 'verify_peer_name=false' SSL context option via php.ini in PHP 5.6

Tags: php, ssl

The case: I would like to open SSL connection to `localhost` while SSL certificate was issues for FQDN.

The problem: Without special handling in line `(*)` the program below fails with the following message:

`PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN='myhost.com' did not match expected CN='localhost' in test.php`

The test PHP program:

```
$fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://localhost:993", $errno, $errstr, 30);

// (*) if commented, the program fails
//stream_context_set_option($fp, 'ssl', 'verify_peer_name', false); 

if (!$fp) {
        die("Unable to connect: $errstr ($errno)");
}
if (!stream_socket_enable_crypto($fp, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT)) {
        die("Failed to start SSL");
}
fwrite($fp, "USER god\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "PASS secret\r\n");
while ($motd = fgets($fp)) {
        echo $motd;
}
fclose($fp);
```

As I have a lot of legacy code, I would love to have a solution by only applying changes to `php.ini` (or CLI), but unfortunately neither of below works:

`php -d verify_peer_name=false test.php`

`php -d ssl.verify_peer_name=false test.php`

Ideas?

References:

- [SSL operation failed with code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26151993/267197)
- [How do I verify a TLS SMTP certificate is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13436527/267197)
- [SSL and PHP streams](http://www.docnet.nu/tech-portal/2014/06/26/ssl-and-php-streams-part-1-you-are-doing-it-wrongtm/C0)
- [SSL solution for PHP 5.6](http://lists.horde.org/archives/horde/Week-of-Mon-20140609/051807.html)
- [OpenSSL changes in PHP 5.6.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php#migration56.openssl.peer-verification)
- [SSL context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php)

Comment: this is just a warning, it shouldn't be failing

Comment: It prints a warning to console, but actually `stream_socket_enable_crypto()` returns 0 (fails).

Comment: Did you find the solution for this ?

Comment: Which PHP version?

Comment: @Thibaut: If you ask me, then I have come to the solution actually as in the below answer, namely, I had to write some PHP code (look [this post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.mail.squirrelmail.user/39936), search for `function sqenable_ssl($stream)`).

Answer (score 12):

## TL; DR

When `cafile` and `capath` are at the same time [runtime configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.configuration.php) and [SSL context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php#context.ssl.cafile), `verify_peer_name` and `verify_peer` are only [SSL context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php#context.ssl.verify-peer).

So those later two can not be modified via runtime configuration directives.

---

I can understand the confusion from the documentation reproduced here under, but those two paragraphs actually refer to two different concept in PHP.

> The default CA bundle may be overridden **on a global basis** by setting
>   either the openssl.cafile or openssl.capath configuration setting, **or
>   on a per request** basis by using the cafile or capath context options.
>
> While not recommended in general, it is possible to disable peer
>   certificate verification **for a request** by setting the verify_peer
>   context option to FALSE, and to disable peer name validation by
>   setting the verify_peer_name context option to FALSE.

[Link to PHP manual source](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php#migration56.openssl.peer-verification)

First note that the documentation itself makes a clear difference between `openssl.cafile` and `openssl.capath` being **on a global basis** or **on a per request** basis versus `verify_peer` and `verify_peer_name` being **for a request** only.

So that basically means that, when `openssl.cafile` and `openssl.capath` can be adapted both via `php.ini` or via `stream_context_set_option`, on the other hand `verify_peer` and `verify_peer_name` are only accessible via `stream_context_set_option`.

This is also confirmed by PHP source code itself, here are some lines showing that `PHP` underlaying `C` language is getting the value from `php_stream_context_get_option` only.

```
must_verify_peer_name = GET_VER_OPT("verify_peer_name")
        ? zend_is_true(val)
        : sslsock->is_client;
```

[Link to PHP github source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/3aaf90df49896ec935abb2351c14fb42028dac2f/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c#L495)

For clarity, here is the declaration of the macro `GET_VER_OPT`

```
#define GET_VER_OPT(name)               (PHP_STREAM_CONTEXT(stream) && (val = php_stream_context_get_option(PHP_STREAM_CONTEXT(stream), "ssl", name)) != NULL)
```

[Link to PHP github source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/3aaf90df49896ec935abb2351c14fb42028dac2f/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c#L96)

When `cafile` and `capath` are actually first matched against `php_stream_context_get_option` value, but then, if those are `NULL` in the context, they are then fetched in the ini configuration.

```
GET_VER_OPT_STRING("cafile", cafile);
GET_VER_OPT_STRING("capath", capath);

if (cafile == NULL) {
    cafile = zend_ini_string("openssl.cafile", sizeof("openssl.cafile")-1, 0);
    cafile = strlen(cafile) ? cafile : NULL;
}
```

[Link to PHP github source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/3aaf90df49896ec935abb2351c14fb42028dac2f/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c#L842)

Then a little lower in the exact same function:

```
if (capath == NULL) {
    capath = zend_ini_string("openssl.capath", sizeof("openssl.capath")-1, 0);
    capath = strlen(capath) ? capath : NULL;
}
```

[Link to PHP github source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/3aaf90df49896ec935abb2351c14fb42028dac2f/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c#L859)

For clarity, here is the declaration of the macro `GET_VER_OPT_STRING`

```
#define GET_VER_OPT_STRING(name, str)   if (GET_VER_OPT(name)) { convert_to_string_ex(val); str = Z_STRVAL_P(val); }
```

[Link to PHP github source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/3aaf90df49896ec935abb2351c14fb42028dac2f/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c#L97)

You can also see that, when those two value [`openssl.capth`](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=PHP_INI_ENTRY%28%22openssl.capath%22) and [`openssl.cafile`](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=PHP_INI_ENTRY%28%22openssl.cafile%22&type=Code) are defined as existing `ini` configuration, the later [`verify_peer`](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=PHP_INI_ENTRY%28%22verify_peer%22&type=Code) and [`verify_peer_name`](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=PHP_INI_ENTRY%28%22verify_peer_name%22&type=Code) are nowhere to be found.

So sadly the only way to go, as the documentation is prompting it, is to configure it for a request via [`stream_context_set_option ( $stream_or_context , 'ssl' , 'verify_peer_name' , false )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-option.php)

---

**In a long gone history**: this was the default value of those two SSL context options. They changed in PHP version 5.6.0, as prompted by the documentation:

> 5.6.0 Added peer_fingerprint and verify_peer_name. verify_peer default changed to TRUE.

[Link to PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php#refsect1-context.ssl-changelog)

Which means that this kind of issue can appear after upgrading PHP from `PHP < 5.6.0` so, the default value of those two options could have been kept to false by sticking to a `PHP` version lower than `5.6.0`; but since the branches `5.*.*` of PHP are now [totally out of support](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) this is not a viable option anymore.

Comment: Excellent answer by the way; I'm [waiting for the bounty period to end](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323729/bounty-etiquette-early-awards) before awarding, but I don't imagine anyone's going to come up with a better answer than this.

Comment: Didn't saw the link to the meta post at first glance in your comment. I think that's totally fair to leave the bounty open, really, don't worry.