# How to get SSL certificate information using node.js?

Tags: php, node.js, curl, ssl-certificate

I've built a PHP version of this using the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081042/how-to-get-ssl-certificate-info-with-curl-in-php/3081093).

Now my problem is that I want to do multiple requests in parallel. I'm already using node.js to do similar requests for NS servers, etc, so it naturally came to mind.

Can somebody help me with that?

As an alternative option, can somebody tell me if there's a way to make it in parallel using only PHP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

For everybody who's facing the same problem, here's the answer:

```
var https = require('https');
var options = {
    host: 'google.com',
    port: 443,
    method: 'GET'
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log(res.connection.getPeerCertificate());
});

req.end();
```

Comment: Don't forget `req.end()` after sending your request or you'll end up in a __socket timeout__

Comment: `res.connection`is deprecated so use `res.socket`. Also `host: ` is officially `hostname: ` according to the docs.

Comment: socket doesn't have `getPeerCertificate` !