# How can I know that a HTTPS endpoint receiving a TLS request from my node.js is using a specified SSL certificate?

Tags: node.js, ssl

I have an endpoint (in any language, let's say Python) that exposes some service as HTTPS using a certificate issued by any widely known and trusted CA, that is 
probably included in virtually any browser in the world.

The easiest part is that I can issue TLS requests against this endpoint using Node.js with no further problems.

For security reasons, I would like to check that every time my Node.js issues a TLS request against this HTTPS endpoint, I want to make sure that the certificate being used, is the certificate that I trust, and the one that was requested by my company.

What is the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: Do you have access to the private key? If not, what about using `fs.read()` and doing a hash comparison of both the remote cert and the copy you have?

Comment: Actually - `fs.readFileSync('https://path/to/remote/cert.pem')` would probably be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the answer at [How to get SSL certificate information using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596315/how-to-get-ssl-certificate-information-using-node-js) would be suitable for your needs.

You can use the following code to get your endpoint's certificate then check its fingerprint or hash against what you expect.

```
var https = require('https');
var options = {
    host: 'google.com',
    port: 443,
    method: 'GET'
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log(res.connection.getPeerCertificate());
});

req.end();
```

Comment: I can just use getPeerCertificate and then I validate the certificate data myself? I wonder if there is a way to provide the public key of the server in the request, and then the SSL Handshake validate it.

Comment: From what I could find that isn't built-in functionality and I didn't see a module for it, however there's a module called ssl-utils (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssl-utils) that makes comparing certs easy.