# MTLS: send client certificate in nodejs soap - and check server certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, soap, certificate, node-soap

I'm trying to send a client certificate from a nodejs app using [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap)

```
const clientURL = 'prod.wsdl';
const wsdl_options = {
           wsdl_options: {
               "cert": fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/client.crt'),
               "key": fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/client.key'),
           }
};
soap.createClient(clientURL, wsdl_options,  function (err, client) {
  if (!err) {
    client[my-method](args, function (error, result) {
    if (error) console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
  
  }
})
```

But I'm getting an error: **{"errno":"EPROTO","code":"EPROTO","syscall":"write"}**

When I'm sending a curl, the server gets my request with the correct cert:

```
curl -X POST https://host:4431/func --cert /etc/ssl/certs/client.crt --key /etc/ssl/certs/client.key
```

what can be the problem here? am I missing something at wsdlOptions?

Also, My customer gave me the certificate of the soap-server (and NOT the ca itself) and I need to check the ssl certificate of this response against the one he gave me.

How can I do that?

for request library we can do: `res.connection.getPeerCertificate() / res.connection.getPeerX509Certificate()` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31553483).

**UPDATE**:

I found the solution to the first issue with the client certificate and key.

I was missing:

```
client.setSecurity
```

After creating the proxy!

For createClient, there is no need to put the cert and key.
So the code now looks like this:

```
const clientURL = 'prod.wsdl';

soap.createClient(clientURL, {},  function (err, client) {
  if (!err) {
    client.setSecurity(new soap.ClientSSLSecurity('/path/to/key','path/to/cert'));
    client[my-method](args, function (error, result) {
        ...
  }
})
```

**Now how can I get the certificate of the server from the response and compare it to the one I have?**

Comment: Searching for this kind of error shows several types of problems, from incompatible TLS stacks, not using the right proxy, accessing a HTTP only server with HTTPS etc. There are not information here to find out what really is the origin of the problem in this specific case and thus it is impossible to show how to solve it. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to improve your question to get better help.

Comment: I think this error is coming due to the fact that the soap server isn't getting the cert file correctly. But I tried the way this module describes how to use it so I'm a little confused here.

Comment: The soap server is https

Comment: _Now how can I get the certificate of the server from the response and compare it to the one I have?_. You don't, the TLS/SSL handshake does this for you. If you have openssl `openssl s_client -showcerts -servername server -connect server:443` will show you the certs of a server. (change the port number to your servers' 4431).