# PHP and SSL: How can I retrieve "detailed" validation results for remote site's certificate?

Tags: php, curl, ssl, openssl

I am trying to validate a remote site's SSL certificate.  Curl can give a generic success or failure indication, but no details. My client requires specifics on WHY the certificate failed:  wrong domain, revoked or expired cert, untrusted CA, etc.

curl_error($ch) returns the proper error when the hostname is wrong on cert.  But it doesn't return any info if the cert is expired or revoked, it returns `"Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates"`which is not correct.

How can I use PHP to get the exact reason a remote site's certificate is invalid / untrusted ??

Looks like Curl can not do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the validity period, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081042/how-to-get-ssl-certificate-info-with-curl-in-php/3081093#3081093)

and added this:

```
    $cert_info = openssl_x509_parse($cont["options"]["ssl"]["peer_certificate"]);

    if($cert_info['validFrom_time_t'] < time() < $cert_info['validTo_time_t']) {
        //Certificate is CURRENT!
    } else {
        //Certificate is Expired or not yet valid
    }
```