# Get SSL information and convert the SSL certificate validFrom / validTo values to a date with PHP

Tags: php, date, ssl, time

I am writing a little script that displays the information of a given certificate taken from a specific website:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$orignal_parse = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$get = stream_context_create(array("ssl" => array("capture_peer_cert" => TRUE)));
$read = stream_socket_client("ssl://".$orignal_parse.":443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $get);
$cert = stream_context_get_params($read);
$certinfo = openssl_x509_parse($cert['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate']);
echo "Name: ".$certinfo['name']."<br/>";
echo "Subject: ".$certinfo['subject']['C']." ".$certinfo['subject']['ST']." ".$certinfo['subject']['CN']."<br/>";
echo "Issuer: ".$certinfo['issuer']['C']." ".$certinfo['subject']['O']." ".$certinfo['subject']['CN']."<br/>";
echo "Version: ".$certinfo['version']."<br/>";
echo "Valid from: ".$certinfo['validFrom']." to ".$certinfo['validTo']."<br/>";
```

For a full description of what the arrays returns go here: [How to get SSL certificate info with CURL in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081042/how-to-get-ssl-certificate-info-with-curl-in-php)

The problem is that `$certinfo['validFrom']` returns a value like this:

```
170904000000Z
```

And I ahave no idea what it is. What I want is to convert `$certinfo['validFrom']` and `$certinfo['validTo']` to a human date format, but I don't know what type of time this is, I thought it was Unix but it didn't work, then I noticed that there is a "Z" at the end of the string:

```
echo "Valid from: ".gmdate("Y-m-d",$certinfo['validFrom'])." to ".gmdate("Y-m-d",$certinfo['validTo'])."<br/>";
```

returns: `Valid from: 7385-09-24 to 7683-11-24`

And that is obviously wrong.

I checked the certificate on the browser and the values:

```
Valid from: 170904000000Z to 180313235959Z
```

Well converted should be

```
Valid from 2017-09-03 to 2017-03-13
```

Thanks

Comment: Try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-read.php#103906

Comment: @marekful that is exactly the answer to my problem, please post it as an answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP documentation for `openssl_x509_parse` says

> The structure of the returned data is (deliberately) not yet
> documented, as it is still subject to change.

but there are some hints on [user comment here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-read.php#103906), like the sample code below. Note, that as quoted above, you shouldn't rely on this array index in production code as it may change w/o notice.

```
$validFrom = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $data['validFrom_time_t']);
$validTo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $data['validTo_time_t']);
```

Answer (score 2):

170904000000Z Isnt it ymdhmsT ? 4th September 2017 at midnight UTC?