# openssl_x509_parse / validTo_time_t gives me "1970-01-01"

Tags: php, apache, openssl

OpenSSL 1.1.1 php enabled for apache

all sites give me "1970-01-01" as an expiry date

```
<?php

$websites = $_POST['websites'];
$websites = explode(',', $websites);

foreach ($websites as $website) :
    $website = trim($website);
    $cert = openssl_x509_parse(file_get_contents("https://{$website}"));
    $expiration = date('Y-m-d', $cert['validTo_time_t']);
    echo "{$website}: {$expiration}<br>";
endforeach;

?>
```

any site gives the same date

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the contents (HTML) of the site to openssl_x509_parse:

```
$cert = openssl_x509_parse(file_get_contents("https://{$website}"));
```

You either need and certificate object or the contents of the actual certificate

```
 openssl_x509_parse(OpenSSLCertificate|string $certificate, bool $short_names = true): array|false
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-parse.php

See: [How to get SSL certificate info with CURL in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081042/how-to-get-ssl-certificate-info-with-curl-in-php) for an example.